# Trying to find a game development competition

Tags: competition

About a month or two ago one of my friends participaded in a game development competition. The theme was "infinity". I think he had either a week or a month to finish the game. The problem is I cannot for the life of me find or remeber the name of the site. (Its not Ludum Dare)

I am hoping someone here might know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This? http://experimentalgameplay.com/blog/2010/09/neverending-in-september/